# Are storyboards still support in future iOS version after ios 13?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

Now that SwiftUI is here, are storyboards still supported in Xcode for iOS13?

Can we still use storyboards for this and future versions of iOS, or do we have to switch storyboards to SwiftUI?

ios 13 is supporting storyboard but can it support future ios version.

Comment: yes you can still use storyboard or SwiftUI, it's up to you

Comment: but do we have to swift to swiftUI from storyboard in future version of xcode?

Comment: No, you can use either. see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `storyboard` is still available.

Whenever you are creating any new project from the Xcode you have to choose about your editor whether you would like to go with `SwiftUI` or `storyboard`.

like this 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

yes, It is still supported in iOS 13